# Hosting a java server program to listen at a port

Tags: java, sockets, ip, client, serversocket

I want to test an application written in Java socket programming. I have a client machine which has a dynamic ip. I want to connect to a server program in the server and send some data. What I did earlier was running the server application in a machine that has a public IP and telling the client to connect to that.

`eg: sendData(data,"192.168.345.65",4480); //data,ip,port`

But I now do not have access to that public ip machine which is at my University. All the other normal internet connections are coming with dynamic IPs here.

How can I test my application. Are there any free services support that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a java enabled server.
You cannot use a use a webhosting because you are using your own server program not webserver.
Need some vps hosting.

Comment: Thank you. What are the free options ? Is there a way to create a public ip via software?

Comment: You cannot create a public IP instead you need to buy it. Let me check about other alternative solutions, I will notify as soon as possible